# function returning most frequent words

Tags: python

I want write function which return most frequent words, with specific requirements:

- show 8 most common words
- words must be longer than 4 signs
- eliminate stop_words
- skip dot and comma

I wrote short function but I don't have idea how connect requirements with my function:

- stop_words
- words must be longer than 4 signs

Example.

txt = '''Python was first released in 1991. It is an interpreted, high-level, general purpose programming language. It is Object-Oriented.

Designed by Guido van Rossum, Python actually has a design philosophy centered around code readability. The Python community will grade each other’s code based on how Pythonic the code is.
Python’s libraries allow a programmer to get started quickly. Rarely will they need to start from scratch. If a programmer wishes to jump into machine learning, there’s a library for that. If they wish to create a pretty chart, there’s a library for that. If they wish to have a progress bar shown in their CLI, there’s a library for that.

Generally, Python is the Lego of the programming languages; find a box with instructions on how to use it and get to work. There is little that needs to be started from scratch.'''

stop_words =  ["a", "to", "if", "it", "across", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "all", "almost", "alone"]

```
from collections import Counter

def words_counter(sample_txt):
    return Counter(sample_txt.lower().split()).most_common(8)
words_counter(txt)

[('a', 9),
 ('to', 8),
 ('python', 4),
 ('is', 4),
 ('the', 4),
 ('it', 3),
 ('code', 3),
 ('they', 3),
 ('if', 3),
 ('there’s', 3)]
```

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: By signs do you mean characters? You can loop through your list of tuples and `remove()` any values who do not have `len(elem) <= 4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with one `generator` and `walrus operator` like the following (for python 3.8+):

```
def words_counter(sample_txt):
    filtered_words = (cleaned for word in sample_txt.split() 
        if (cleaned := word.strip('.,').lower()) not in stop_words
        and len(cleaned) > 4)
    return Counter(filtered_words).most_common(8)

>>> words_counter(txt)
[('python', 4),
 ('there’s', 3),
 ('library', 3),
 ('programming', 2),
 ('programmer', 2),
 ('started', 2),
 ('scratch', 2),
 ('first', 1)]
```

Or with few `generators` aka `lazy looping`:

```
def words_counter(sample_txt):
    without_dot_comma = (word.strip('.,') for word in sample_txt.split())
    longer_than_4 = (word.lower() for word in without_dot_comma if len(word) > 4)
    without_stop_words = (word for word in longer_than_4 if word not in stop_words)
    return Counter(without_stop_words).most_common(8)

>>> words_counter(txt)
[('python', 4),
 ('there’s', 3),
 ('library', 3),
 ('programming', 2),
 ('programmer', 2),
 ('started', 2),
 ('scratch', 2),
 ('first', 1)]
```

**EDIT:**
Change the last line in the function to:

```
return [(v, k) for k, v in Counter(filtered_words).most_common(8)]
```

Comment: If I want improve function. How revert value? For example ```[(4, 'python'),
 (3,'there’s'),
 (3, 'library')]```

Comment: @jarxinho what do you mean by revert values? Do you want to print the least common?

Comment: I want return: (number_of_occurrences, word)

Comment: @jarxinho check the edit

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to first create a new list of words, eliminating all those that don't match the two conditions, and then build the `Counter` from that list.

By the way, your code ignores the requirement to skip dot and comma.

```
import re
from collections import Counter

def common_words(text, stop_words, min_length):
    # requirement 1: get rid of dot and comma
    clean_text = re.sub(r'[.,]', '', text)

    # requirement 2: create list of words that are longer than min_length characters and not in stop_words
    words = [ word for word in clean_text.lower().split() if len(word) > min_length and word not in stop_words ]

    # now count like you did before:
    return Counter(words).most_common(8)
```